# MS Access to SQL Server connection

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, ms-access

I'm using MS Access as my database, my hosting is not supporting this, and I need to know how to convert MS Access to SQL Server connection string?

This my code of data connection:

```
'--------------- ole parameters -------------------
Dim olecommand As Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand
Dim oledataadaptor As Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
Dim odbcDataSet As System.Data.DataSet

Sub populate_dataset_Access_accdb_test(ByRef ds As DataSet, ByVal sql As String)
    Dim myDataConnection As New OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("myodbc").ConnectionString)
    olecommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand
    olecommand.CommandText = sql
    odbcDataSet = New System.Data.DataSet
    olecommand.Connection = myDataConnection

    myDataConnection.Open()
    oledataadaptor = New OleDbDataAdapter(sql, myDataConnection)
    oledataadaptor.Fill(ds)

    myDataConnection.Close()

End Sub

Sub insert_dataset_Access_accdb_test(ByVal sql As String)
    Dim myDataConnection As New OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("myodbc").ConnectionString)
    olecommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand
    olecommand.CommandText = sql
    odbcDataSet = New System.Data.DataSet
    olecommand.Connection = myDataConnection

    myDataConnection.Open()
    olecommand = New OleDbCommand(sql, myDataConnection)
    olecommand.ExecuteNonQuery()


    myDataConnection.Close()

End Sub

Sub cr_ds(ByRef ds As DataSet, ByVal sql As String, ByVal tablename As String)
    Dim myDataConnection As New OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("myodbc").ConnectionString)
    olecommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand
    olecommand.CommandText = sql
    odbcDataSet = New System.Data.DataSet
    olecommand.Connection = myDataConnection

    myDataConnection.Open()
    oledataadaptor = New OleDbDataAdapter(sql, myDataConnection)
    oledataadaptor.Fill(ds, tablename)

    myDataConnection.Close()
End Sub
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Assuming you've moved your data from an access db to a sql server available to your website try looking at [Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server connection strings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-ole-db-provider-for-sql-server-sqloledb/)

Comment: Just changing the connection string won't really solve your problem ..... you'll have to basically **rewrite** your entire code base to go against SQL Server ....

Answer (score 1):

As Steve Wellens pointed out, you miss some basic things here. Since your host does not support your data source type (MS Access), **changing your connection string is not enough**. You have to use a data store supported by your hosting service. I suppose that [Microsoft SQL Server](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/default.aspx) is one of them, but you have to verify it by contacting your hosting service administration support.

Regarding the transfer of data between MS Access and MS SQL Server, you could get some guidance [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/access-help/move-access-data-to-a-sql-server-database-by-using-the-upsizing-wizard-HA010275537.aspx).

Regarding the MS SQL Server connection strings, you could get some help from [this post](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2012/) but you have to verify the availability of the MS SQL Server database with your hosting service.

Hope I helped!

Comment: I don't think MS Access needs to be 'supported' by the server.   It's basically just a file with no active code on the server.   It should be deployable anywhere.  I believe he just has a bad connection string.

Comment: You are right, MS Access files need no server. But even this passive file needs some dlls to be used, usually installed with the MS Office suite. If these dlls are not supported, then you cannot actually use them (you would have to make many tweeks to use them).

Comment: The dlls, I mean assemblies, to access MS Access are installed with .NET:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6cd7c08%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Perhaps you are right. I thought that you had to install MS Office on the server, but I cannot insist on that.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just change an Access connection string to an SQL connection string and have things work.  You would have to port your data From Access to the SQL Server.

I think it is more likely that when you deploy your Access database to the server, the path is different.  You probably need to modify the config file to point to to where the Access file is on the server.

Comment: I already modify it  but my error showing when I try execute the data

Comment: Do you think someone can help you fix an error when you won't tell them what the error is?

Comment: An OLE DB Provider was not specified in the ConnectionString.  An example would be, 'Provider=SQLOLEDB;'. 
  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Comment: Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: An OLE DB Provider was not specified in the ConnectionString.  An example would be, 'Provider=SQLOLEDB;'.

Source Error: 



Line 14: 
Line 15:     Sub populate_dataset_Access_accdb_test(ByRef ds As DataSet, ByVal sql As String)
Line 16:         Dim myDataConnection As New OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("myodbc").ConnectionString)
Line 17:         olecommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand
Line 18:         olecommand.CommandText = sql